# How to solve none symmetry system of equations in Real numbers?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this system of equations in the set of all real numbers.
Solve the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
 x^3+y (y-z)^2=2, \\
 y^3+z(z-x)^2=3, \\
 z^3+x(x-y)^2=8.
 \end{cases}$$
I tried
From the given system, we have
$$x^3 + y (y - z)^2 ) + 2 (y^3 + z (z - x)^2) - z^3 - x (x - y)^2 = 0.$$
I am trying to factor it. But I can not.
How to solve this system of equation?

Comment: What’s the context? Are you trying to find all solutions, or some solutions? Are the variables supposed to be integers, rational numbers, real numbers or complex ones?

Comment: There’s a very simple solution in integers which you can find by inspection, or trial and error.

Comment: I want to find all solutions in real numbers .

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Any other conditions?

Comment: @RamanujanXV There is no  other conditions. I used Mathematica and get unique solution $(1, 1, 2)$.

Comment: You face a polynomial of degree $27$ with only one real root